# Converting encrypted messages to unencrypted results of an equally hard to reverse function

Tags: time-complexity, cryptography, encryption

If we have some function, $f$ with an exponentially sized domain, mapping the set $\{0, 1\}^N$ to $\{0, 1\}$, could we do something like this:

For ease, let's say $E(x) = x^e (\text{mod} \; n)$. This is the encryption function.

Now, let's say we represent $f$ with some $x$. I'm not exactly sure how this can be done---maybe $f$ can be represented as a circuit or something like that?

Our subject then encrypts $f$'s representation using $E$---$E(f)$---and broadcasts this to their peers.

The peers receive this encrypted function, and want to call it on some values $\{a, b, c, \cdots\}$ and obtain the result.

Because $f$ is hard to reverse without any information on its implementation (it will take $O(2^N)$), this doesn't break encryption.

I think this may relate to homomorphic encryption---we want to perform the operation of calling $f$ with input $a$, and compute an output. The difference is that we don't want to the result to be encrypted.

Is there any method of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, if you're willing to involve the holder of the private key.  Let $U$ be a universal circuit, so that $U(f,v)=f(v)$.  (There will be some upper limit on the size of circuit $f$ that is supported by $U$.  Presumably that will be OK.)  Then you can use [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) to encrypt $f$ and then compute an encrypted form of $U(f,v)$ from the encrypted form of $f$.  Whoever holds the private key can then decrypt to obtain $U(f,v)=f(v)$.

---

No, I don't think this is not possible, if you want it be done without cooperation of the holder of the private key and you want to be able to recover the value $f(v)$ in unencrypted form.  If there was some such protocol that allowed anyone to compute $f(v)$, given $E(f)$ and $v$, then that would mean the encryption is not secure.  In particular, it would violate [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).  You say it "doesn't break encryption",   but in fact it does violate the standard requirements for encryption to count as secure.  Also, for many function classes, given many input-output pairs $(v,f(v))$, it is often possible to recover $f$, which would be a total break of $E$.

Perhaps there is some way to formulate the problem so that $E(f)$ must not leak anything more than ability to compute $f(v)$ for any choice of $v$.  I suspect that would be a pretty weak form of encryption, but perhaps it could be possible to create such a scheme.  I don't know how, though.

---

You might also be interested in [Yao's garbled circuits](https://web.mit.edu/sonka89/www/papers/2017ygc.pdf), which has some limitations but is an adjacent space to what you asked for.

Comment: Hello. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough in my question, but I wanted the person who "calls" the encrypted function to be able to find the value (i.e. you don't need the private key to retrieve $f(v)$). In homomorphic encryption, $E(f) \cdot E(v) = E(U(f, v))$. But I would like some protocol such that $E(f) \cdot E(v) = f(v)$---it doesn't break encryption, as computing the inverse of $f$ is hard.

Comment: I'm looking into a paper on ["Private Function Evalution"](https://encrypto.de/papers/HKRS20.pdf). I think it may be a solution.

Comment: @abokifas, see updated answer.

Comment: Looking into it, you may be right that there is no way to do this without collaboration. But if Alice and Bob can communicate during "decryption," the Private Function Evaluation protocol seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @abokifas, cool!  I encourage you to write an answer to your own question explaining that solution.